# Truffle console: Accessing contract using an account other than owner

Tags: truffle-console

I have the following contract:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.5.0 < 0.7.0;
 
contract SimpleContract {
  string  public name;
  address private owner;
  constructor() public {
     name = 'abs'; 
     owner = msg.sender; 
  }
  function getName() public view returns(string memory) {
      return (name);
   }
   modifier onlyOwner(){
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      _;
   }

   function changeName(string memory _name) public onlyOwner{
      name = _name;
   }
}
```

It works if I access through the owner's account:

```
truffle(development)> await SimpleContract.getName()
‘abs’
```

But I want to access the functions through a non-owner. I am trying the following:

> truffle(development)> await SimpleContract.start({from: web3.acc1})
> Thrown: TypeError: SimpleContract.start is not a function
> at evalmachine.:1:24
>
> truffle(development)> await
> web3.eth.accounts[1].SimpleContract.getName(); Thrown: TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'SimpleContract' of undefined
> at evalmachine.:1:30 reentrancy:

Somebody please guide me how to access the contract using a non-owner.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to retrieve the accounts:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(acc){ accounts = acc })
```

Then, for instance, if you try to call the `changeName()` function from a different address than the contract creator, transaction will revert:

```
await SimpleContract.changeName('Sergi', {from: accounts[2]})
```